# How to sum part of a column according to values in another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Struggling with an excel formula - I have been trying SUMIF and IF(SUM()) statements for a while. I have 2 columns of data. I have duplicate different ID codes in column B and the values I want to add in column K shown below. I am trying to write a formula that will go down each row that says sum all the K #'s in the column that are the same (ie. all are from ID EEE) into the last goal column. I want to use that goal column so I can divide a smaller value (J2) into the goal total of all the EEE ID codes. MY issue if that my formula keeps summing the whole column K. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
B:ID  K:#    What I'm trying to retun:
EEE   500    950
EEE   450    950
MMM   400    400
MMM   0      400
III   350    350
```

what I've been trying to do: `=J2/SUMIF($B$2:$B$322667, B2, $K$2:$K$322667)`

Comment: `=SUMIFS(K:K,B:B,B2)` and drag down?

Comment: It's still giving me the sum of the whole column unfortunately instead of just the few values from EEE, MMM, etc :/

Comment: Unable to repro. https://i.stack.imgur.com/64HQm.png. Maybe I misunderstand what your actual goal is.

Comment: You were right! There was another criteria I needed to add into the SUMSIFS that I was missing, but your formula was right. Thank you so much!